# str_replace_all() Won't Detect Return or New Line "\\r\\n"

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm loading a .csv file as a string on R with readLines(). One of the columns contains Tweets with undesired line breaks.

I need to delete the line breaks. In Notepad++, Searching for: `\r\n` and Replacing with `%%%` works, and the whole file turns into one single line.

However, when doing this in R, neither `str_replace_all()` nor `str_remove_all()` will detect `\\r\\n`, and the output file is identical to the input. This is my code. I've tried the following RegEx: `"\n"`; `"\r\n"`; `"\\n"`; `"\\r\\n"`;`"\\r"` to no avail.

```
tx  <- readLines("line_breaks.csv", warn = FALSE)

tx <- str_replace_all(tx, "\\r\\n", "")

write_lines(tx, "C:/Users/u0126720/Documents/csv_test/one_line.csv")
```

I've also tried:

```
tx <- str_remove_all(tx, "\\r\\n")
```

Input file looks like this:

```
date,tweet
Wed Jun 19 2019, Como pretendia ser un angel , estando rodeada de demonios? ✨

Rp.

hola, estas en la olla?"
```

Desired output (and what I get with Notepad++):

```
Wed Jun 19 2019, Como pretendia ser un angel , estando rodeada de demonios? ✨Rp.hola, estas en la olla?"
```

Comment: Does your file only have one record? If you get rid of all the new lines you'll only have one big line in the end. The way `readLines` work you should get a vector of character values that don't have any newlines, those have been split into separate values. Maybe `paste(readLines("line_breaks.csv"), collapse="")` will help. Otherwise how do you tell the difference between "real" line breaks and those you want to get rid of?

Comment: Indeed, the problem was in the way I was reading the file. And no, I have several thousand lines like that. Thanks! BTW I'd like to upvote your solution, but it isnt posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new answer because my previous one did not answer the correct problem, but I left it because it may useful for others.

If your file is a properly formated csv file then you should be able to read it in as csv even with the CRLF inside the data.

```
tx  <- read.csv("line_breaks.csv", colClasses= stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However from your sample input file it looks like the csv is not well formed (it is missing a `"` after the first comma on line 2.

EDIT: What is happening in your case is that `readLines` is reading `\r\n` as a new line (as it should) and the following text is put in the next entry of the vector. So `\r\n` will not appear in `tx`.

EDIT: How are you getting your input files? If you can fix that method so produces proper csv files with quotations, then R will be happy with it.

Comment: The data is JSON files converted to CSV via an online tool. The JSON files were obtained using the Twitter API. The asymmetrical quotes and unexpected CRLF are part of the content of the tweets or in user bios, etc. I've found a way around this using readLineswhich I'm posting as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to make sure there's one line per tweet, i.e. I needed to delete all CRLF except those before a line that starts with the first column i.e. date. 
I solved this by using a place holder `%%%` instead of LFs, and then by adding a LF before each cell of the date column using `gsub()` and a Regular Expression:

```
tx <- paste(readLines("C:/Users/u0126720/Documents/csv_test/test.csv", encoding="UTF-8"), collapse="%%%")
tx <-gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)%%%([S|M|T|W|F]{1}[u|o|e|h|r|a]{1}[n|e|d|u|i|t]{1} [J|F|M|A|S|O|N|D]{1}[a|e|p|u|c|o]{1}[n|b|r|y|l|g|p|t|v|c]{1})", "\n\\1", tx, ignore.case = FALSE, perl=TRUE, fixed=FALSE)
```

This results in the following:

```
date, tweet
Wed Jun 19 2019, Como pretendia ser un angel , estando rodeada de demonios? ✨Rp.hola, estas en la olla?"
Wed Jun 19 2019, RT @ignacioschmied: Mi hermano @maitan_69 está realizando
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use four backslashes to match a slash in R's regex. This is because in regex, backslash is used for control characters and some wildcards and in R, backslash is also used for control characters. So if you put `"\\r"` in R, the regex will see it as `\r` and then try to match CR. Try:

```
tx <- str_replace_all(tx, "\\\\r\\\\n", "")
```

Comment: This would work if there were literal "\r\n" values (with the slashes) in the input. But that doesn't appear to be the case in the input. There are just actual new line values. You wouldn't need to escape any slashes in that case. This doesn't seem right at all. This works just fine: `stringr::str_replace_all("one\r\ntwo", "\r\n", "")`

Comment: @missuse Adding slashes doesn't do the trick.
@MrFlick Hi, as I said in my question, ```\r\n``` doesn't work. The output file is the same as the input one.

Comment: Are there CR and LF in the input or `"\r\n"`1?

Answer (score 0):

I have it working for me with gsub("\n", "", tx, fixed=T), which is R base. you could adapt it to remove both or run it twice.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything either. The output file looks the same as the input file, and I can still find \n and replace with "" manually on Notepad++
Edit: There was a problem with the way I was reading the file. See above.